# how to create background watermark in CFReport

Tags: coldfusion, crystal-reports, coldfusion-9, cfreport

I want how to create background watermark (especially Image) in CFReport just like appearing "**Developer Edition**" text in CFReport when we render if our CF version is developer edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special band called "Watermark" I think, but from what I remember it wasn't easy to position it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that ability is available, you can probably just add an image to the section you would like the watermark and move it back in the layer order, however that will likely only span that section and not the entire page.

Additionally you can programatically add a watermark use

```
<cfpdf 
    action="addWatermark" 
    copyFrom="TTTraining.pdf" source="test.pdf" 
    rotation="15“   position="100,0" foreground="true" overwrite="yes" 
    destination="myPDFWatermark.pdf">
```

Comment: You're talking about existing pdf file. What I want is I want to add background watermark by using CFReport and displaying on the fly.

Comment: You can use cfreport to generate the pdf on the fly then add the watermark. However as the other user suggested there is a watermark band you can select this top right then add your watermark there.

Comment: yap, your way is 3 steps to do. I want to do CFReport like crystal report's "underlying sections belows"